# Visualizing a desktop application

Tags: vb.net, cloud, desktop-application

I have a legacy VB.NET application that I would like to virtualize so my clients can access it from the cloud.  Currently, I have an Azure VM that hosts the app and exposes it to the customers via RDS. Everything is working fine, but I am not 100% happy with the performance.

I would love to be able to convert it into a web application, but unfortunately this is not feasible at the moment.

I was wondering if there is a better way of doing this or perhaps there is a better platform that I could use.

Thank you.